# kendo UI: can I use conditions in a bound template?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I have this template:

```
<script id="tmpl_bound_menuitem" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li data-bind="attr: { class: style }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: href }, text: name"></a>
    </li>
</script>
```

A View uses that to create menu items from a menuModel:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="source: menu_test" data-template="tmpl_bound_menuitem"></ul>
```

This works fine. But if I set this data:

```
menuModel.set("menu_test", [
    { name: "MenuItem1", href:"#/route1" },
    { name: "",         style: "divider" }
]);
```

The result has undefined values, as expected:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="source: menu_test" data-template="tmpl_bound_menuitem">
    <li class="undefined" data-bind="attr: { class: style }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: href }, text: name" href="#/route1">MenuItem1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider" data-bind="attr: { class: style }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: href }, text: name" href="undefined"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, the question is: is it possible to make this template work for different types of menu items?

Something like the javascript code in "normal" templates:

```
# if(href) { #<a data-bind="attr: { href: href }, text: name"></a># } #
```

But this doesn't work here because href is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use conditions.

If you write `if (href)...` you need to have `href` defined otherwise JavaScript will not find it. So, instead, what you should write is:

```
# if(data.href) { #<a data-bind="attr: { href: href }, text: name"></a># } #
```

Where `data` is the variable that KendoUI automatically generates containing your object model.

Kendo UI allows to shortcut to `href` because in the JavaScript code they have something like:

```
with (data) {
   // Code for expanding your template
   ...
}
```

But this requires having `href` otherwise the template expansion cannot determine if `href` is a global variable or a member of data.